# TypeDescriptor ConvertFromInvariantString throws exception?

Tags: c#

It looks like a bug but why does the following code throw an exception:

```
TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(decimal)).ConvertFromInvariantString("1,234,678.90");
```

Comment: I don't think this is a _bug_, I think someone made a _choice_ to not allow thousands separators in the input string.

Comment: Try decimal parse which allows the commas : decimal.Parse("1,234,678.90", NumberStyles.AllowThousands)

Answer (score 0):

Both `Convert.ToDecimal("1,234,567.90", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` and `decimal.Parse("1,234,567.89", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` work. So maybe invariant string doesn't imply invariant culture? I guess it's because there are no thousands separators in `1000m.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` either. –